# Excluding a controller from production code

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, integration-testing

We are trying to exclude certain controllers from our production code (we expose certain endpoints for API manipulation required by our integrated UI tests)

Have a look at the following snippet, can you see anything fundamentally wrong by following this approach?

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = true)]
public class NonProductionAttribute : ApiExplorerSettingsAttribute, IActionFilter
{
    public NonProductionAttribute()
    {
        IgnoreApi = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT") == EnvironmentName.Production;   
    }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context) { }

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        if (IgnoreApi)
        {
            context.Result = new NotFoundResult();
        }
    }
}
```

So basically we simply decorate the "offending" controller with the NonProduction attribute, I am inheriting from ApiExplorerSettingsAttribute to exclude the controller from generated documentation.

A concern might be the use of the Environment variable, perhaps somehow get it from IHostingEnvironment?

Or would you suggest a completely different alternative(for excluding controllers that is)?

Comment: You could put the environment variable in the web.config and then transform the config for each environment. I've done this before to great effect

Comment: I think the env variable part of this is fine, except you could abstract this using [config](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration#using-options-and-configuration-objects), only negative that springs to mind is that you'll have all these non-prod routes in your route table. It also feels a little risky, there's a risk if it's done wrong things could leak to prod. You could look at a build time process to do the same thing.

Comment: @Matt my initial design involved the build process only including what is needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move all "TestOnly" MVCControllers and/or ApiControllers to it's own Area. That helps you identify the Test-Only-Code much faster too.

In your AreaRegistration, simply don't register any routes based on the Server / Environment your on.

If you don't specify the Route, asp.net will return a 404 for you.

You could even go that far, to move all your test code to it's own assembly and include this (if required) and don't even build/deploy it on prod. https://blog.longle.io/2012/03/29/building-a-composite-mvc3-application-with-pluggable-areas/

Comment: I attempted the areas approach (.net core) but had issues getting it to route properly on my mac... (works fine on my older projects) Perhaps I must give it a shot again? Probably just missed something small

Comment: Ahh success :D, think I will follow this approach